looking for a word meaning trimming eyebrows
What is the word used for when the eyebrows are 'trimmed' and shaped for beauty by pulling out a certain number of hairs using tweezers or suchlike?
I think it is 'plucking eyebrows. Maybe 'picking eyebrows'? Maybe both work? Or maybe just 'trimming eyebrows'?
Many thanks

The question asked about trim, pluck, and pick eyebrows -- these terms would be used to describe different actions with different goals:
If I have long straggly eyebrow hairs that I need to shorten, I would use the term trim my eyebrows to describe using a scissors or a similar edged tool to shorten individual hairs, similar to a haircut for the hair on my head or the beard trimming that some men do. (In my personal experience it's generally only men who might need to trim overly bushy eyebrows, but both men and women might sprout individual long hairs that benefit from being trimmed (shortened).)
If I have eyebrow hairs growing in places where I do not want them, such as too far towards the bridge of my nose or too far towards my eye sockets, I would use the term pluck my eyebrows to describe using a tweezers or similar tool to pull individual hairs out by their roots.  (Note that cyclical fashion trends may call for more or less extreme eyebrow plucking; I, personally, have plucked my eyebrows into a variety of shapes over the years.  The term plucked eyebrows typically refers to eyebrows that have obviously been reduced from their natural shape.)  (In cultures that I am familiar with, it's typically only women who reshape their eyebrows in this way, though beauty standards are becoming more androgynous.)
Ref: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pluck-eyebrows "pluck your eyebrows -- to pull out some of the hairs from your eyebrows ( line of short hairs above each eye in humans) in order to change their shape"
(There are other techniques, such as waxing and threading, which can also be used to remove undesired hairs by their roots.)
If I want to completely remove my eyebrows, for example to paint on the appearance of eyebrows in a very different shape or location, I would use the term shave my eyebrows to describe using a razor or similar tool to truncate all of the hairs at the surface of the skin.  (This is a very uncommon beauty technique, but not unknown.)
If I have a skin condition that makes my eyebrow area itchy, I might pick at my eyebrows to attempt to remove the irritation; this is rarely a healthy approach to the situation. (Compare with someone who might pick at a scab which may alleviate itching but will slow down healing.)

The practice is different for men and women. Not the same at all. Eyebrow plucking for women is not about "long straggly hairs". It's about keeping an eyebrow shape clean., which might include removing a long hair here and there, but once you have your basic shape, you don't wait for long straggly hairs to grow...

I'm not sure what was unclear about my answer, @Lambie .  Both men and women can grow individual long straggly hairs that benefit from trimming, but in Western society it's typically only women who aggressively reshape their eyebrows through plucking or other methods.

My eyebrows have always been thick and as I have aged not only do they have increasingly more white hairs but some eyebrow hairs have indeed become quite wild-looking and exaggerated in length (to my alarm) so I will snip the longer ones with a pair of nail scissors and color the white ones with a mascara brush.

@Mari-LouA Yes, I do the same thing only I use a light brown powder. For me, it looks more natural. [haha]


What is the word used for when the eyebrows are 'trimmed' and shaped for beauty by pulling out a certain number of hairs using tweezers or suchlike?

Trimming has a different meaning and not pulling out or removing excess hair.

Reference Cambridge dictionary
trim.
verb [ T ]
trim verb [T] (CUT).
to make something tidier or more level by cutting a small amount off it:

(The beautician may also trim the remaining hair on the eye brow)
"Thin eyebrows are often considered aesthetically pleasing, but beauty is subjective and varies from person to person.".
A common general word for removing excess hair on the eyebrow is
"Eyebrow shaping".
It has other names depending on the procedure involved:

threading
plucking (with tweezers)
waxing
sugaring
Laser hair removal

Note : Depilatory cream hair removal. (Not normally used for eyebrow shaping)

lasers aren't usually used on eyebrows. And often, one does trim them with scissors.

@James Laser is not usually used on eyebrows. It can be, but it’s not common, just like it’s unusual to use it for the hair on your head, even though it can be. Compared to plucking and trimming with scissors, laser treatment on eyebrows is vanishingly rare, to the point that many laser clinics don’t even offer it.

@JanusBahsJacquet I agree with you that it might be dangerous. I know of someone who did for chin. The parlour told that it has to be done in multiple sittings. They promised permanent solution but in the end it was waste of money.
